# Implement Swipe feature in custom keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, swipe, ime

I have implemented a custom keyboard using following tutorial
[Custom Keyboard](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615)

How to add swipe feature to it?

  or
How to handle Touch event in the custom keyboard?

or
How can I record keys values pressed between onpress and onrelease event in the keyboardeventlistener?